# Yii phpunit error SeleniumTestCase.php fail to open stream

Tags: php, yii, phpunit, autoloader, spl-autoloader

I have installed phpunit based on the instructions in this website (the 'Windows' sub-menu in the right side menu bar) for Yii:

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html

When I run my database connection test:

```
phpunit unit/DbTest.php
```

I get the below error:

```
require_once(PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php) failed to open stream. No such file or directory in C:/wamp/www/yii/framework/test/CWebTestCase.php on line 12
```

Then I googled the error and tried the following instructions (which don't work)
    1. Install phpunit using pear (no longer supported)
    2. Download phpunit/extension folder from github and put it in my C:/wamp/www/yii/framework/test/ . Then the error become:

```
Cannot redeclare class PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase in C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\test\PHPUnit\Extensions\SeleniumTestCase.php on line 1217
```

How should I fix this? I am using Windows 8 with wamp server.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
pear upgrade -f phpunit/phpunit_selenium
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: PEAR is no longer supported for installing PHPUnit, see https://thephp.cc/news/2015/01/phpunit-migration-from-pear-to-phar

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and followed the exact same steps as you included; trying pear and putting the PHPUnit folder inside tests.
 
**To fix your final error** you just need to comment out the following line (in my code it was on line 12) in: 
*yii-framework/framework/test/CWebTestCase.php*

```
//require_once('PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php');
```